# QGIS 3.20 issue with print composer - layers not aligned

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

I have installed QGIS 3.20 and found that when moving from the canvas to print composer all my layers have moved, and do not line up anymore.They look fine each time I go back to the main canvas, but as soon as I load a map into print composer all my layers have moved and no longer line up as they should. I have tried reinstalling with no joy. QGIS 3.18.3 still works fine. If you save the map to a PDF the layers have moved back to where they should so they are only misaligned when viewing in print composer.

The first image below shows as it should be and the second is the misaligned print composer layer.

[image: Aligned image from canvas]

[image: Misaligned image in print composer]

Comment: where does the base imagery come from? a local source or via the web?

Comment: It is Google Earth

Comment: What about the CRS of your layers?

Comment: I have checked the CRS and they haven't changed. I have tried to change the CRS but that doesn't help. I have switched back to 3.18 for now as I have no issues running that version. As mentioned, the error is only in the print composer and when I save to PDF, it is how it should be, so it is only a visual error in print composer